# SnipCart site: "$localize" showing up in Google search result snippet

Tags: localization, google-crawlers, noscript, snipcart

I have customized my [SnipCart](https://snipcart.com/) e-commerce site following the [customization documentation](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/customization):

```
    <div hidden id="snipcart" data-api-key="MY_KEY">
        <address-fields>
            <div>
                <div class="snipcart-form__row">
                    <div class="snipcart-form__field snipcart-form__cell--large">
                        <snipcart-label class="snipcart__font--tiny" for="address1">
                            {{ $localize('address_form.address1') }}
                        </snipcart-label>
```

However, now I see $localize showing up in Google search results instead of the English text.

[image]

Google Search Console shows that the SnipCart .js resource (.css too) is blocked because of cdn.snipcart.com/robots.txt (which is configured to not allow crawling of anything). This seems to be the problem.

What is the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case someone else stumbles into this.

You can prevent certain content from showing up in the snippet with the  `data no-snippet` directive, for example:

```
<span data-nosnippet>Don't show me</span>
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags#data-nosnippet